# Error in SQL syntax manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1064

```
 Create table Enroll(usn varchar(10),
                     course_id varchar(10),
                     attendance int(10),
                     marks int(10,2),
                     foreign key(usn) references bmsStudent(usn),
                     foreign key(course_id) references Course(course_id)
                    );
```

Error1064(42000): you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',2),.... ' at line 1

Help me resolve error in my SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you strictly need decimals in marks column, Use Decimal instead -

```
marks DECIMAL(10, 2),
```

Answer (score 1):

when you can't have two parameters in an int.

change

```
   marks int(10,2),
```

to

```
   marks int
```

note: this should be easy to figure out for you -- the error message tells you the part of the query ",2)" and there is only one place where that occurs in your input so you know exactly where the error is without asking us.